# How to establish connection to cli when updating to Version 1.0.1 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I installed Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.4, I can connect through cli, but when I tried to update to Version 1.0.1, an error prompted:

```
Can not establish connection with jdbc:iotdb://172.16.32.228:6667/ : Socket is closed by peer.. Host is 172.16.32.228, port is 6667.
```

Seems like I need to change my settings but I don't know where to change them. Any guidance on this problem?

I was expecting to know how should I change the settings so I can run the newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the ip configured by ConfigNode and DataNode of Apache IoTDB.
For ConfigNode, try to set `cn_internal_address` to 127.0.0.1, and set `cn_target_config_node_list` to 127.0.0.1:10710.
For DataNode, try to set `dn_rpc_address` and `dn_internal_address` to 127.0.0.1, and set `dn_target_config_node_list` to 127.0.0.1:10710.